# Differences in EIOPA S.06.02.0x QRTs (Assets D1 in 2016)

Tags: solvency-ii

As per the [COMMISSION IMPLEMENTING REGULATION (EU) 2015/2450](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32015R2450) (published 31DEC2015) I can see that S.06.02.01 QRT relates to *Quarterly* (or annual if exempt) quantitative templates for *individual* undertakings, and that S.06.02.04 relates to *Quarterly* (or annual if exempt) quantitative templates for *groups*.

My question is.. What do the S.06.02.02 and S.06.02.03 QRTs relate to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-S.06.02.02 does not exits because the anual code S.06.02.01 is reused for the quarterly reporting. Note that there are not changes in comparison with anual table structure.

-S.06.02.03 does not exits for day 1. Note that this last ".03" means Day 1 Solo.

The idea of the codification is to reuse (when possible) the same codes as far as the table structure is the same. This helps to easily see the commonalities or to highlight that there are differences in the templates without needing to compare the business logs. Also it may also help on the database mappings and to reduce the number of worksheets.

You can find more information [here](https://dev.eiopa.europa.eu/Taxonomy/Full/2.0.1/EIOPA_DPM_Documentation_2.0.1.pdf) in point IV.3.2.1 and [here](https://eiopa.europa.eu/Publications/Reports/EIOPA-BoS-15-115_Final_report_ITS_Regular_Supervisory_Reporting_rev_08092015.pdf) at the bottom of page 5. The entry points matrix available in the EIOPA reporting formats page helps to see how the logic is been applied.

Comment: This can also be verified on the latest copy of the annotated templates - see "entry points" tab:  https://dev.eiopa.europa.eu/Taxonomy/Full/2.0.1/EIOPA_SolvencyII_DPM_Annotated_Templates_2.0.1.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the ITS, and can't find any reference to those templates. I suppose they got lost in some reshuffling.

Comment: My suspicion is that it may be due to typos in that linked document..  It would kinda make sense to have separate template IDs for the Annual vs Quarterly submissions, so they can be identified as such (the actual templates may be identical).

Comment: But the template referenced for annual submission is 06.02.01 as well.

Comment: So my suspicion was wrong.. It was all explained in the taxonomy.  Templates are re-used when the formats are identical..